# Using encryption on Parse

Tags: android, ssl, encryption, parse-platform, openssl

Now that parse is opensource, how do I ensure my connection to parse and my  android app is encrypted? 
I'm not using heroku or any other hosting services. But I'm deploying the server on an actual server in my professor's lab.

Could someone please tell me the procedure for implementing encryption between the parse server and my android app.

Comment: Setup an HTTPS connection with an SSL certificate. That is how encryption is managed on a simple level in regards to the server. I am not sure if parse's open source server still handles encryption, but I do know passwords are still hashed from what I have seen.

Comment: Yes I see that the password is hashed. But since this is app to be used for medical research, I need to setup encryption or https connection. Could someone please let me know any method to use encryption or HTTPS in the parse server.